# Selecting data from 3 tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to make a query to get user's name and his/her code_number from 3 tables according to login_id. I have 4 tables named login, tutors, institutes and students.

This is my tables' structure.

> **login table**
>   login_id
>   login_type
>
> **tutor table**
>   tutor_id
>   login_id
>   tutor_name
>   tutor_code
>
> **institute table**
>   institute_id
>   login_id
>   institute_name
>   institute_code
>
> **student table**
>    student_id
>   login_id
>   student_name
>   student_code

When an user logged into the site login_id save on SESSION and then I need to check what kind of user has logged in and after identified the user then need to get logged in user's name and code.

My problem is how I check which user (in the case Tutor, institute, student) has logged into site and how can I get its name and code?

Hope someone help me about this...
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the `name` and `code`, then you can just `JOIN` on the tables. Your query will be similar to this:

```
select l.login_id,
  l.login_type,
  coalesce(t.tutor_name, i.institute_name, s.student_name) Name,
  coalesce(t.tutor_code, i.institute_code, s.student_code) Code
from login l
left join tutor t
  on l.login_id =t.login_id
left join institute i
  on l.login_id = i.login_id
left join student s
  on l.login_id = s.login_id
```

The `COALESCE` will return the first non-null value.  If the login can only belong in one of the tables, then using this will return the correct value even if the user is a `tutor`, `institute` or `student`.

If you want to return this in separate columns, then you could use:

```
select l.login_id,
  l.login_type,
  t.tutor_name,
  t.tutor_code,
  i.institute_name,
  i.institute_code,
  s.student_name,
  s.student_code
from login l
left join tutor t
  on l.login_id =t.login_id
left join institute i
  on l.login_id = i.login_id
left join student s
  on l.login_id = s.login_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. both queries work for me. can I know which one is most suitable. I never use 'COALESCE' in my select query before.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan it really depends on what you need. If you only want one column with the name, then use the `COALESCE` version, otherwise use the other. They both are the same except for the columns being returned. :)

Comment: @TharangaNuwan I joined your room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24271/tharanga-nuwan

Comment: check this my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824791/how-do-i-modify-this-select-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it with `CASE` by checking the Login_Type:

```
SELECT 
    CASE Login_Type
        WHEN 'Tutor' THEN Tutor_Name
        WHEN 'Institute' THEN Institute_Name
        WHEN 'Student' THEN Student_Name
    END Name, 
    CASE Login_Type
        WHEN 'Tutor' THEN Tutor_Code
        WHEN 'Institute' THEN Institute_Code
        WHEN 'Student' THEN Student_Code
    END Code
FROM Login L
    LEFT JOIN Tutor T ON L.Login_Id = T.Login_Id
    LEFT JOIN Institute I ON L.Login_Id = I.Login_Id
    LEFT JOIN Student S ON L.Login_Id = S.Login_Id
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 'CASE' is completely new to me in select query

Comment: @TharangaNuwan -- no problem -- CASE basically works like IF ELSE IF ELSE... Hope it helped.  Good luck.

Comment: @sgeddes.. can I have a solution wiht CASE to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824791/how-do-i-modify-this-select-query-in-mysql